# meta-analysis of long-term probabilities

Tags: probability, meta-analysis

I have a following question. In case of the most widely available data are 2-year probabilities of an event in a single cohort, is it possible to run a meta-analysis of probabilities per cohort? If no, is there a way to convert probabilities with CIs (as cohort A vs B) to OR with CIs? I have experience in cardiovascular meta-analyses, but not in epidemiological/oncology field, hence my doubts.
Thank you

Comment: All you have is the P(event) in the cohort?  No risk adjusted estimates?

Comment: I have two-year probabilities (%, 95%CI) of univariate analysis of serostatus on clinical events.

Comment: It is not completely clear what data you have. Does each cohort give rise to exactly one proportion and then you want to combine them?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to perform this meta analysis?  Yes.  Should you?  We would require more details to determine that.  You would also need to determine if a fixed or random effects model is best.  I'm not very familiar with meta analysis so I will let someone else reply to that.

As for converting between probabilities to odds ratio for A vs B, that should be simpler.  Given the estimate $p_1$ for group $A$, and $p_2$ for group $B$, the odds ratio would be

$$\log(\widehat{OR}) = \log \left( \dfrac{p_1(1-p_2)}{p_2(1-p_1)} \right) $$

The large sample variance for this estimator is

$$ \hat{V}[\log (\widehat{O R})]=\frac{1}{n_{1} p_{1}\left(1-p_{1}\right)}+\frac{1}{n_{2} p_{2}\left(1-p_{2}\right)}$$

And so you can compute CIs by computing

$$ \log(\widehat{OR}) \pm Z_{1-\alpha/2}\sqrt{\hat{V}[\log (\widehat{O R})]}$$

and then taking the anti-log of these quantities.